# Selenium Webdriver returns background-color with strange alpha value

Tags: c#, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

to get the background-color of a WebElement I use:

```cs
string color = IWebElement.GetCssValue("background-color");
```

Where Selenium returns me something like:

```cs
color = "rgba(153, 255, 255, 1)"
```

Inspecting the element using firebug or something I get `#99FFFF` without any transparency. In fact, the element is totally opaque configured and displayed.

So I wonder where the alpha value `"1"` is coming from. As I understand it there should be a `"255"` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is correct if the element is totally opaque.

The alpha channel in an RGBA colour value is in the range 0.0 > 1.0 with 1.0 being completely opaque. So what you're getting back sounds like it's correct.

As per: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp

If you cross browser test this, I suspect you may get some varying results though. Pretty sure when I was looking as CSS properties at one point Chrome was returning RGBA values, where IE was giving me standard RGB + a separate opacity value.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html?topic=html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetCssValue.htm) says: "... method is likely to be unpredictable in a cross-browser environment."